# Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor'

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am trying to create an HTML Form in Spring Boot which takes values entered in the form and inserts it into a database
For this I am using Spring Data JPA to create a repository and save it.

So , getting to the question , I tried actually searching for the answer here and tried one solution but it didn't work.
I basically told me to remove `th:field="*{}"` from the input tag and just replace it with `field="{}"` , it did load the page but the I couldn't POST the values.

I am sharing my code below :

Student Model :

```
package com.example.demo.Student;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int studentId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String studentName;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String studentPassword;
}
```

Student Controller

```
package com.example.demo.Student;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class StudentController{
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;
    @PostMapping("/registrationPage/registration/add")
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("Student") Student student){
        studentRepository.save(student);
        return "Added Successfully";
    }
}
```

maincontroller

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(
            @RequestParam(name="name",required=false,defaultValue="World") String name,
            Model model
    ){
        model.addAttribute("name",name);
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/registrationPage/registration.html")
    public String registration(){
            return "/registrationPage/registration";
        }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Welcome to Student Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1 th:text="|Hello,${name}!|"></h1>
    <a th:href="@{/registrationPage/registration.html}">Register Here</a><br>
    <a th:href="@{/signInPage/signin.html}">Sign In</a>
</body>
</html>
```

registration.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Register Student</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${Student}" method="post">
        <label>Enter Student Name : </label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{studentName}"/><br/><br/>
        <label>Enter Student Password :</label>
        <input type="password" th:field="*{studentPassword}"/><br/><br/>
        <button type="submit">Register User</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```